# "Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites." But how did someone edit my meta post?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, meta

I was going to do some grammar fixes on a random meta (Stack Overflow) question. But when I clicked the *edit* button, it gave an error message.

> Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites.

But some of my posts on meta have been edited. How did they edit my post if suggested edits are not allowed on meta?

Comment: Anyone with the [edit questions and answers privilege](/help/privileges/edit) (2000 reputation on Stack Overflow) do not need to "suggest" edits (which are reviewed by [Suggested edits queue](/help/review-suggested-edits)) they can simply make edits that take immediate effect. There is no suggested edits review queue for questions and answer on Meta (though there is one for tag wiki/tag wiki excerpt suggested edits). The effectively means only users with full editing privileges can make edits (to questions and answers) here..

Comment: See also: [Why can't I suggest edits on SE meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87890/1099857)

Comment: Do we really not have a canonical for this on MSO?

Comment: Suggested edits for ***tag wikis*** are indeed enabled on meta sites...

Comment: Hum, not "too surprised" by the Policy if Edits are "*random*", :shock: , ah-ah...! // I also find it a bit of a "pity" sometimes, I regularly see some "interesting"/useful (as Answerer) Formatting (only) used on Meta that I would like to know how "they" do it, and hit the 'Edit' Button/Link to see the Markup Source..., to be stopped with the same Error Msg, the 'Edit' Link should simply be disabled or hidden for "us", =Users with <2k-Rep...

Comment: @chivracq you can still review the revisions as a <2k user, and from there you can review the [source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/bf3d6c31-0b98-4821-9468-ae13c3345b09/view-source); not as ideal I admit, but it is a workaround.

Comment: Oh..., yep!!!, that's a "good one", @Larnu, I didn't think about it, and the "Side-by-side Markdown" Tab from the Revisions is also useful for "that Purpose"... Thanks...