# How is the Stack Overflow for Teams Enterprise version deployed?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-enterprise

I read that the Enterprise version offers managed cloud and [on-premises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-premises_software) deployment.

Is this managed cloud different than [SaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service) which is available in the free, basic and business versions?

What are all the deployment offerings in all the versions? And how are they different?

Comment: "*I read...*" => [Source](https://stackoverflow.co/teams/pricing/#compare): "*Hosting: Single tenant (cloud or on-premises)*"

Comment: Can anybody from support reply on this?

Comment: If you make "any Edit" to your Post, (like for example adding the Link I provided in my previous Comment), => that will "bump" the Thread automatically and will get "more eyes" on it and hopefully some Mod or "knowledgeable User" will notice it... :idea:

Comment: @chivracq Given that editing *just* to "bump" a question is against the rules, please don't recommend to people that they should do so. Yes, editing to *materially improve* their post is recommended, but your statement here is devoid of the context and caveats regarding editing to "bump". Please don't make such a recommendation again without a much more detailed explanation. Better, would be to point the user at any of a few MSO/MSE posts, e.g. "[On Meta, how do you get attention for questions without an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266782/3773011)"

Comment: @Makyen, yes of course, I was just trying to "help", you have a potential Customer for 'Teams', a commercial Product, and still no Answer on a pre-sales Inquiry after 3 days, which doesn't look very "professional" to me, just saying... (And I thought they could anyway add the Link to the Documentation I had provided...) // But OK, sorry about that and don't worry, I won't try to "help" again... // EDIT: Oh well, it "worked" a bit apparently, some Staff-Member just posted an Answer to OP...

Comment: @chivracq: [The Stack Overflow for Teams product page](https://stackoverflow.co/teams/) explains the different tiers of Teams, and has links to contact us for more info. MSO isn't really the best place to ask questions about Teams that only staff can really answer – it's better to contact our sales team via the form on the site I linked for that. (And to clarify, Makyen is a volunteer moderator of the Stack Overflow site, not a staff member.)

Comment: Yeah, @V2Blast, don't need to explain "to me", I would have found the "proper" Communication Way, I didn't start the Thread / ask the Question, I'm just a User on the Site and I was just trying to help your poor potential Customer, who would have been happy to get so much attention from 1x Mod + x2 Staff Members 3 days ago...

Comment: @chivracq Helping is good and appreciated. Your concern and desire to help are well placed. Thank you. I'm not asking you to stop helping. I'm really just asking you to change how you do it a bit. In this case, pointing the user to the MSO post I linked would have been good. You could also have edited the question yourself to add the pertinent information you were recommending be added and/or adjust the tags. It also would have been reasonable to raise a custom mod-flag asking for status-review to be added in order to bring it to the attention of SE staff.

Comment: @Makyen, "*You could also have edited the question yourself*" => Nope, [can't do so](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419547/3799241), look at my Rep... :idea: // Custom-Flag => Nope, I don't do "Custom-Flags" anymore, they (nearly) always get "Declined" and feel too much like "Russian Roulette"... // But Thanks anyway for the (nicer) Reply...

Answer (score 3):

Enterprise is a very different offering than our Free, Basic, and Business tiers. When you create a team here on Stack Overflow on one of those tiers, you're getting a team that is hosted on a shared infrastructure with all other teams. It cannot be installed or moved elsewhere.

Enterprise, on the other hand, is a full site controlled by you in a private environment (and can even have Teams enabled on it so that you can have a main site with as many private teams as you want). This site can either be hosted by you on your own infrastructure, in which case we would send you an installer to set it up and each time an update is available, or we can manage the instance for you. When we manage it for you, the site is hosted in its own cloud environment that isn't shared by other instances. We're essentially installing the software into the cloud and maintaining it rather than you installing it.

If you'd like more details about Enterprise, you'll need to reach out to our sales team to discuss more in-depth the infrastructure requirements of the offering as well as the pros and cons of hosting on-premises versus having us manage it.